# What does "a bit unfortunate" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, dialogue

I'm translating dialog with "***bit unfortunate***" phrase:

> Sasha:"It's a bit *unfortunate* about Antony's final take." 
>   (final take corresponds to final record in sound-recording studio. He had a lot of records before final one)
>
> Sergey:"Huh? Sasha, are you praising him? That's rare."

As I can say, Sasha said something good about Antony. But I can't understand, what did he mean. **a bit** means **small/little** and **unfortunate** means **bad luck**, so it's rephrased version is:

> Sasha:"Antony's final take was really lucky".

Why it is **lucky**? For me, *lucky* isn't complimentary word at all. If Sasha said "*it is good*" then it would make sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sasha is not praising Antony.

***"a bit unfortunate"*** means something bad or untoward had happened during Antony's final take.

My interpretation would be that Antony really did well with all the recordings before the final one, where something went wrong. Sasha is expressing her concerns/disappointment/remorse towards Antony's final take regarding the same.

In short, according to the original conversation between Sasha and Sergey, the rephrased version should read:

> Sasha:"Antony's final take was (really) **unlucky**".

Here, **unlucky** is parallel with **unfortunate**. I wouldn't use ***"really unlucky"*** because it goes on to emphasize that Antony's final take was a total disaster. Since Sasha is suggestion only ***"a bit unfortunate"***, she suggests that Antony's final take was not a total flop, but only a minor disappointment.